# How to handle (filter out) infinity in MAPE score in R

Tags: r

I put a forecast model together and when using accuracy in forecast I get Infinity for some of the *MAPE* scores.
I understand why I get the infinity and I'm not trying to fix that right now.
I want to understand how to filter out the infinity rows in my data frame.  If I convert MAPE to numeric using `is.numeric` the infinity translates to **455**, why?
I've also tried to subset the data frame with `[which(df$MAPE == "Infinity"),]` and I've tried `[which(df$MAPE == "âˆž"),]` and neither finds any values.

Comment: What about `is.infinite(df$MAPE)`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up feeding the accuracy statement in R the entire forecast instead of just the MEAN.  This product of this was a new metric MASE which more accurately handles time series data that has missing values or 0's.